# Getting limited data from database using ajax in asp.net core mvc

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

i create a form where i get data from database using loop in asp.net core.i do paginition in that form where i just display 5 items on a page. But Now i have another data which display on that page but i do not want to include into the pagination. So is there any ajax or another solution for it

My view:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
                {
                <div class="embla__viewport">
                    <div class="embla__container">
                        <div class="embla__slide">
                            <div class="embla__slide__inner">
                                
                                    <img src="@item.pic1" />
                                   
                                <h2>@item.city | <a href="#">Map</a></h2>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="for_sale">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        @item.price price
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <a href="#" class="arrow">
                                    <svg class="home_svg" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#22577e"
                                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path d="M13.5 8.25L17.25 12M17.25 12L13.5 15.75M17.25 12H6.75" stroke="#22577e"
                                              stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                    </svg>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                  }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Rent(int PageNumber = 1)
        {

            var data = rdb.GetDataHouse();
           
            ViewBag.Totalpages = Math.Ceiling(data.Count()/5.0);
            data = data.Skip((PageNumber - 1)*5).Take(5).ToList();
            return View(data);
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new `PaginatedList` class to handle pagination:

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

            this.AddRange(items);
        }

        public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;

        public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

        public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
```

For specific usage and implementation, please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

As for another set of data that you don't want to include in the pagination, you can use [ViewData/ViewBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0#weakly-typed-data-viewdata-viewdata-attribute-and-viewbag) to pass it to the page.

Here is a [complete example](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/data/ef-mvc/intro/samples/cu-final).

**Edit:**

Now that the top ten items remain the same, you can take the top ten items from the database and pass them to the View via the `ViewBag`:

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? pageNumber)
        {
            var students = from s in _context.Students
                           select s;
            
            ViewBag.Data = students.ToList().Take(10);

            int pageSize = 3;
            return View(await PaginatedList<Student>.CreateAsync(students.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
        }
```

View:

```
@model PaginatedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>

<h2>Index</h2>

<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Last Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    First Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Enrollment Date
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Data)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.LastName
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.FirstMidName
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.EnrollmentDate
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Last Name
            </th>
            <th>
                First Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Enrollment Date
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
}

<a asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
   class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
    Previous
</a>
<a asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
   class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
    Next
</a>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry i think you not understand my question i mean that i just want to show same data on all pagination pages. i show same data in another div in which i required to pagination but in this div i do not want to paginate also i have to restrict the data. and i show the same data on all page which occur by pagination .

Comment: Same data? Why do you want to display the same data twice in a paginated div and a non-paginated div?

Comment: i want to display the first 10 records as an example and then in other div i want to display all records including pagination

Comment: In the non-paginated section, do you want to always display the first ten records, or do you want to switch with the paginated section? @Qasim Asghar

Comment: yes i want to always display the first ten records

Comment: I updated my answer, is this what you want? @Qasim Asghar